# How can I modify a value in a struct?

Tags: collections, struct, variable-assignment

My struct class:

```
public struct PinAndRadius
{
    public string pinID { get; set; }
    public string radiusID { get; set; }

    public string getPinID()
    {
        return pinID;
    }

    public string getRadiusID()
    {
        return radiusID;
    }
}
```

the method with a problem:

```
void mapArea_VE_PinDragged(double latitude, double longitude, object id)
{
    foreach (var pin in pinRadiusCollection)
    {
        string ID = id.ToString();
        //string newID = ID.Substring(0, 18);
        if (!pin.Key.pinID.Equals(ID))
        {
            continue;
        }
        else if (pin.Key.pinID.Equals(ID))
        {
            var newLoc = createNewSearchLocation(latitude, longitude);
            mapArea.VE_DeleteRadius(pin.Key.radiusID);
            drawPoly(newLoc, pin.Value.xar_Radius);
            pin.Key.radiusID = pollyID;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I try to set `pin.key.radiusID` to pollyID, I get an error saying

> Cannot modify the return value of 'System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair.Key' because it is not a variable...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I simply just changed the struct definition to a class.

Comment: Do you understand the differences between structures and classes?  Changing to a class will make the code compile, but the semantics are different from what they would be if you used a struct.  Some situations require struct-like semantics (in which case one should use the approach I suggested), while others require class semantics.  If a variable of type `PinAndRadius` gets stored in a collection, and then the variable's `RadiusId` is subsequently changed, do you want the `RadiusId` of the one in the collection to also change?  If you do, a mutable class would be appropriate.  If not...

Comment: ...then a mutable class is the wrong thing to use (since changing a property accessed through one reference to an instance would change the property seen by all references to that instance).  With relatively few exceptions, each mutable object instance needs to have exactly one owner at any given time, and any code holding a reference to a mutable object needs to know whether it owns the object in question.  There's no formal mechanism for keeping track of who owns what, but passing promiscuous object references around without knowing who owns them is a recipe for bugs.

Comment: in this case, the collection should will change frequently as i will be deleting from it hence why i have used a mutable class, im quite new to C# so im very greatful for the explanation you've provided, really helped

Comment: If you use a mutable class, then saying `myCollection.Add(myThing)` and then saying `myThing.someProperty = 23;`, the result will be that the collection holds a reference to a thing whose `someProperty` value is 23.  If that's what you're after, then your type should almost certainly be a mutable class.  If that's not what you're after, then using a mutable class is apt to be dangerous.

Answer (score 0):

Structure in .net is value-type. This mean you can't get reference to `PinAndRadius` using `pin.Key`. You will get copy of  `pin.Key` of type `PinAndRadius`. Then you haven't access to this copy and compiler tell you about this. In C++ terms it not l-value.

**If you create `struct` always try make it immutable. Mutable structs are evil.**

Simplest way to solve this problem is to make `PinAndRadius` as `class`.

Answer (score 0):

By the looks of it, your `pinRadiusCollection` is a generic dictionary keyed by `PinAndRadius`; the error you're getting is letting you know you can't modify that object because it's being used as the key in your dictionary.

If your pins are supposed to be mutable, you should probably revisit how you're storing them.

Answer (score 0):

Collections in .net are not set up to allow convenient modification of struct-type items contained therein.  Despite this, mutable structs still offer cleaner semantics than any other kind of data type.  To edit a struct held in a collection, simply copy it to a variable, edit that variable, and store it back:

```
var temp = myList[someIndex];
temp.SomeVield = whatEver;
myList[someIndex] = temp;
```

Note that it's generally better to have mutable structs expose their contents as fields than as properties.  Some people may say mutable structs are evil because their semantics differ from classes, but that's like saying screwdrivers are evil because they make lousy hammers.  Exposed-field structs don't work like class types, but structs where all fields are exposed all have the same semantics as each other.  Those semantics differ from classes, but for cases where they're useful, they have no equal.

Incidentally, much of the bad reps "mutable structs" got was a result of the fact that mutating struct members *other than exposed fields* would often generate bogus code if applied to read-only structures.  If you avoid having struct members which modify fields of `this` [it's perfectly safe for static struct methods to modify fields of structures received as `ref` parameters], those dangers don't apply.